# Ubuntu 14.04.1 Trusty crashing / being unresponsive

Tags: linux, ubuntu, crash

Disclaimer: I am not an experienced linux user, and I am trying to diagnose a case where my Ubuntu goes away, and doesn't come back. The PC is a headless PC without keyboard and mouse plugged in, that is usually controlled via SSH / WLAN, but with the option to plug in peripherals.
I have a keyboard plugged into the PC, and the crash is so bad that even pressing numlock does not do anything anymore. The keyboard doesnt react.

I have tried the following:

- Pressing numlock to check if there is any reaction
- Plugging in a screen
- ALT-PRINTSCR+R,E,I,S,U,B pressed with about 5 seconds between each press
- CTRL-ALT-F1 etc to see if I get a terminal
- Checking syslog / dmseg / pm-powersave.log for bad errors.
- Ran memtest, no memory errors.
- Disabled X on boot for now.

None of these has turned up anything. My kernel log is continuously growing, and then abruptly stopping at one point. I went for lunch, came back, box was dead. After hard resetting the box I get logs in my kernel log again, so I assume the crash is pretty bad, if there is not even the occasional log message in the kern.log

I have disabled X on boot, the crash still occurs.

Could anyone advise what a systematic approach to tracking down the problem is?

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling Linux from a USB drive? My experience with Ubuntu 14.04 has been that it identified the hardware and installed all needed drivers without my intervention.

Comment: +1 Seeing the same thing with 14.04 on an AMD box. Running the
RHEL6.6 and Windows 8.1 partitions never fail. Ubuntu always fails usually after ~ 10 minutes. It does not respond to ping so maybe try: 1) Boot a debug kernel (Is there one?)
2) kgdb via a serial cable?